# Calculate monthly statistics for WRF outputs using wrf-python

Tags: python, netcdf, cdo-climate

I use wrf-python in order to read in WRFOUT files.

```
wrflist = [Dataset("wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_00:00:00"),
           Dataset("wrfout_d01_2012-12-02_00:00:00"),
           Dataset("wrfout_d01_2012-12-03_00:00:00"),
           Dataset("wrfout_d01_2012-12-04_00:00:00"),
           Dataset("wrfout_d01_2012-12-05_00:00:00")]

p_join = getvar(wrflist, "P", timeidx=ALL_TIMES, method="join")

print(p_join)
```

I have the daily files containing hourly output for a month. How could I calsulate the monthly means for a specific variable. Something equivalent to cdo monmean?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't mind a CDO based response, I would simply take the time average for each file

```
for file in wrfout_d01_2012-12-??_00:00:00 ; do 
    cdo timmean $file ${file}_monmean.nc 
done
```

and then you can get the mean over the ensemble using

```
cdo ensmean ${file}_monmean.nc out.nc
```

HOWEVER!  This is only valid for the instantaneous fields in the WRF file.   For the fluxes you need to use sum instead of mean, and/or do some unit conversions. I tend to extract a list of flux/non flux variables I need with cdo selvar, and then only work on those (also because the standard WRF output contains a *ton* of stuff you don't usually need).